# iptables - how to improve security and allow dns?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I don't understand much about iptables, i'm running a server which is only used to run a vpn. Here's my iptables-save:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
*security 
:INPUT ACCEPT [5009091:774424925] 
:FORWARD ACCEPT [12157619:10323709607] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7902591:10593610117] 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
*raw 
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [17169079:11098272834] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7902591:10593610117] 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
*nat 
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:104] 
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] :OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:268] 
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4:268]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 1800:2000 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1888 
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.73.240.212  COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
*mangle 
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [17169079:11098272834] 
:INPUT ACCEPT [5011455:774563027] :FORWARD ACCEPT [12157624:10323709807] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7902591:10593610117] 
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [20060210:20917319724] 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
*filter 
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] 
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [410:134179]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -i tun0 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1888 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -j DROP 
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -i tun0 -o eth0 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -d 10.8.0.0/24 -i eth0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -j DROP  
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  1 00:14:41 2013
```

This isn't allowing me to ping from the server, or use yum update. Any suggestions? Also wondering if there are any security flaws apparent.

Comment: You might create a save file (`iptables-save > save`), comment all the rules out, then uncomment them one at a time, or one chain at a time. That would probably help narrow down the potential culprits.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 2):

The output of `iptables -L -nv` includes counts of how many times (and how many bytes) a rule has matched.  The numbers in the square brackets above are these counts for each table policy.

Run that command, try your `ping` or `yum update`, run the command again and see which rule count has incremented by one.  Now you know which rule is blocking what you want to do.

My guess is that it will be one of your two rules with `DROP` targets, which doesn't actually tell you very much.  The next thing you'll need to know is what kind of packet it was and for that you need logging.  Put this in just before the `DROP` rules:

```
-A INPUT -j LOG
```

The meta data of the packets that hit this rule will be logged in `/var/log/messages`.

Once you know what kind of packet `yum update` or `ping` causes to hit your firewall and be dropped, it should be a simple matter to add a rule to allow that packet.

---

DNS queries are allowed out of your system because there is no outbound filtering but DNS queries are usually UDP and UDP is stateless so the responses are not allowed back in by any `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rules.  You will need rules specifically for UDP with a source or destination port of 53.  DNS requests over TCP can be covered with a `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` rule.

---

Allowing all outbound traffic is not the *most* secure configuration, however it is a common one as restricting this ends up being a lot of work adding exceptions.  If your box is truly as single-purpose as you say, you should be able to restrict outbound traffic quite significantly such as by only allowing TCP requests on port 80 to a set of rpm mirrors, only allowing DNS requests to your configured DNS resolver and not allowing any other sort of outbound traffic.

Similarly, your INPUT chain can list IP addresses or ranges that it will accept SSH connections from and reject all others.

Comment: I think this is pretty good advice, with the exception of `RELATED,`.  I have no idea why this gets cargo-culted into so many firewalls, and I think it's inadvisable, since it turns the definition of legal traffic into a question of "what kernel modules are loaded".  I've never seen a circumstance where the blanket acceptance of `RELATED` traffic was necessary, and I'm against it.  Rest of this answer is very good advice, though.

Comment: Guilty as charged.  I copied-and-pasted `RELATED,ESTABLISHED` here without bothering to think about what it means.  I suspect that's exactly the reason it ends up in so many firewall sets.  It's always worth thinking about exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Amen to that, and thanks for being so gracious to my (churlish) objection!